# PyDub can't find ffmpeg

Tags: python

I'm a neophyte Python dev trying to add sound effects to a game I'm working on. Unfortunately, I'm having some problems.

I have `pydub` installed, and when using it in conjunction with `pyaudio`, I can play basic .wav clips. However, I'd like to do things like play them asynchronously or adjust the volume, and I'm gathering that I'd make things easier for myself if I have `ffmpeg` running.

I've installed `ffmpeg` via `pip install ffmpeg-python`, but unfortunately, it looks like `pydub` can't find it. I get these warnings in the console when the program fires up:

```
C:\Users\pete\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Users\pete\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:184: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
```

As you would expect, when I uninstall `pyaudio` and try to force `ffmpeg` to handle the audio, the program crashes.

Where am I going wrong? Am I misunderstanding what `ffmpeg-python` is doing for me and need to install `ffmpeg` separately?

Or am I completely wrong-headed in my approach, and should be able to do what I want (for now, just asynchronous (and potentially overlapping) playback and volume control) by making smarter use of `pydub` and `pyaudio`?

Comment: any ffmpeg library is just going to be a wrapper that calls the ffmpeg application installed on the computer. You don't need an additional library, you'll need to install ffmpeg on your system (and make sure it's on PATH if on Windows).